# Get 'Minimum Order Value' For specific payment method Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to call the minimum order value for a specific payment method within a block and have not been able to find a question that has asked this. The closest bit of code I could find was something like below that finds min value for free shipping:

```
private $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) {
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

public function getFreeShippingValue()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```

I however want the minimum order value and am unsure how to find the path for payment method configurations. I want something like below however and to know how to figure out the paths so guessing and asking questions on here are not required in future:

```
public function getMinLeasingValue()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('paymentmethods/banktransfer/min_order_value', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find path in the `etc/adminhtml/system.xml` file of corresponding module. For the offline-payments it is:

> magento/module-offline-payments/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

For the check money order it would be:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/checkmo/min_order_total', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

For the purchase order:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/purchaseorder/min_order_total', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

For the bank transfer payment:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/banktransfer/min_order_total', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

For the Cash on Delivery:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/cashondelivery/min_order_total', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Comment: Awesome i think its also the same to look in the core_config_data table as my research since asking the question seems so suggest. I will give this all a go.